# Developer Security Training .NET / JAVA

Tags: java, .net, professional-education

Hello my team is tasked to perform security focused training for developers (.NET and JAVA). I have used WebGoat to demonstrate OWASP Top 10 type security vulnerabilities and am looking for a similar tools / software to for demo and labs to cover security focused topics in .NET and Java. The goal is to show insecure code and then how to write secure code

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
http://pentestlab.org/10-vulnerable-web-applications-you-can-play-with/

and this:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Appendix_A:_Testing_Tools

or just google for vulnerable web application for learning penetration testing.